# RSS with list of Kernel releases per distro - is there such a thing?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, rss-aggregator

Is there any place that aggregates Linux kernel releases, on a per-distribution basis, in an RSS feed?

There's a bunch of distros that I'm working with (CentOS 7+8, Ubuntu versions, Rocky and so on), and it's turning out to be quite a headache to keep tabs on all of them.

The major version isn't enough, since I need to know of each and every distro's exact kernel version release.

For instance, when RedHat 7 releases the following kernel, I'll need to see it in the list:
3.10.0-1160.88.1.el7.x86_64

So, even seeing "3.10.0-1160.88" isn't enough.

So, is there?

Answer (score 1):

One possible way to accomplish is to use monitoring software like Nagios, configure agents to extract the exact information you need and add plugin like [this](https://exchange.nagios.org/directory/Addons/APIs/RSS) to create RSS feed.
When you install monitoring server and agents you can get whatever you want (just need eventually to write sample plugin(s) for agent and server) from "clients" and traverse it via agents to server. Then server report the numbers and you create RSS from these reports.

Comment: Thanks, Romeo. This is actually a vary good idea, if the RSS is regarding my own machines. It becomes a bit trickier when they're not, and this is my case :-)

Comment: You could advice you yum-updatesd (RedHat) and apticron (Debian), but they send you notification by email when new packages are available (kernel or other). If the purpose is to get systems up to date (and less vulnerable), why are you restricted to the kernel ?

Comment: @bizna, when you install monitoring server and agents you can get whatever you want from "clients" and traverse it via agents to server. Then server report the numbers and you create RSS from these reports.

Comment: @Romero, I don't any "clients" I can work with. There are actions that I need to perform when kernel versions are out for multiple distros. And that's without having the multiple distros running constantly.

Comment: @Frederic, I won't start registering myself to a dozen or so mailing lists, and for my purpose there's no need for anything other than to know that new kernel versions are released for specific distros.

Comment: @bizna, so you search for kind of web aggregation tool. This make the things quite different. Check the idea with mailing lists. And consider what do you want more: latest or stable one.

Comment: @bizna, maybe here will be more appropriate for your question: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/